# Creating optimized graphics for iOS 2d game

Tags: performance, optimization, graphics, cocos2d-iphone

Is there any guideline for creating optimized graphics for an iOS 2d game. Actually I want to create graphics that can be rendered more efficiently in ios device in terms of memory usage and cpu usage both and take less disk space as well if possible. So is there any benchmark for creating optimized graphics for such games like setting what value of alpha, image quality and other attributes?

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with different pixel formats and use textures in PVR format.

Check this tutorials (there are not updated but the info is still accurate)

http://allseeing-i.com/Performance-tips-for-Cocos2d-for-iPhone

http://www.raywenderlich.com/2361/how-to-create-and-optimize-sprite-sheets-in-cocos2d-with-texture-packer-and-pixel-formats